# pass local declaration of NSDictionary to performSelector

Tags: cocoa, nsdictionary, selector

How it do so that I will not need to put data object right in selector call method?

code with warning (Local declaration of data) :

```
NSDictionary *data = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"SiluetaImage", @"ACTION", silueta_id, @"siluetaid", siluetaTyp_id, @"siluetatypid", nil];
[self performSelector:@selector(downloadBinDataForTyp:data:) 
           withObject:@"SiluetaImage" 
           withObject:data];
```

code without warning :

```
[self performSelector:@selector(downloadBinDataForTyp:data:) 
           withObject:@"SiluetaImage" 
           withObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"SiluetaImage", @"ACTION", silueta_id, @"siluetaid", siluetaTyp_id, @"siluetatypid", nil]];
```

the selector:

```
- (void)downloadBinDataForTyp:(NSString *)typ data:(NSDictionary*)data
{
    ASINetworkQueue *q = [self queue];
    NSString *sUrl = @"url_web_service";

    ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:sUrl]];
    NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [[self getMsg] length]];

    [request setTimeOutSeconds:60];
    [request addRequestHeader: @"Content-Type" value:@"text/xml; charset=utf-8"];
    [request addRequestHeader: @"SOAPAction" value:_action];
    [request addRequestHeader: @"Content-Length" value:msgLength];
    [request setRequestMethod: @"POST"];
    request.userInfo = data;

    [request appendPostData:[self getMsg]];
    [request setDelegate:self];

    [q addOperation:request];
    [q go];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSDictionary *data = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"SiluetaImage", @"ACTION", silueta_id, @"siluetaid", siluetaTyp_id, @"siluetatypid", nil];
[self performSelector:@selector(downloadBinDataForTyp:data:) 
           withObject:@"SiluetaImage" 
           withObject:data];
```

In this you are passing `data` whose scope is just to the method. And outside the method it can not be accessed, as it is getting `release`d.

Comment: Yes I got it, but isn't there a way to do it so that it will not be released? So that data will continue with the selector call.

Comment: Make it a property or ivar.

Comment: If it was property or ivar it would change at the time what I don't want.

Comment: Who will change? How will it change? You are the coder you know when to change it. Isn't it?

Comment: I will change it when creating another httpRequest to queue. Hm, and when I use it to set httpRequest.userInfo and put to the queue it will not change for that request? Will it hold values for the request when i create another request to the queue with the same property and different values?